# Studying the pointwise and uniform convergence of $f_n(t)= \int^{t}_{0}f(x^n)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let:

> $f:[0,1] \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ continuous. $(f_n):[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ : $$(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) \: (\forall t \in [0,1]) \: \: \: f_n(t)= \int^{t}_{0}f(x^n)dx $$

My approach was to first study the pointwise and uniform convergence on $[0,1)$.

Let $t = 0$, $f_n(0)= \int_{0}^{0}f(x^n)dx=0$, thus $f_n$ converges pointwise to 0.

Let $0<t<1 $, $f_n(t)= \int^{t}_{0}f(x^n)dx = F(t^n)-F(0) \underset{n \infty}{\rightarrow} F(0)-F(0) = 0 $
Thus $f_n$ converges pointwise to 0.

Now the uniform convergence on $[0,1)$:
$||f_n - f||_{\infty}=||f_n||_{\infty} = ||\int^{t}_{0}f(x^n)dx ||= ||F(t^n) - F(0) ||_{\infty}$

Let $G_n(t) = F(t^n)-F(0)$, I now will study the variation of $G_n$ to find the upper bound of $G_n$.
$G_n^{'}(t)=(nt^{n-1})(f(t^n)) $, thus $G_n^{'}(t)=0$ when $t=0$ or $f(t^n)=0$.

And here I get stuck. $G_n(f(t^n))$ could be the upper bound of $G_n$ but it could also be the lower bound.

Comment: Your approach to what? You've just defined a function...